# In a quadratic extension, does the orthogonal complement of trace have a nice name?

Tags: galois-theory, quadratics, trace

The trace of an element in a quadratic extension is the sum of it with its conjugate.  Is there a name for the difference between it and its conjugate?

Comment: It's the square root of the discriminant.

Comment: That lacks a sign.  This map should be skew-symmetric with respect to conjugation.  I want to call it the "different" but I can only find this in terms of ideals, not elements.

Comment: Sorry. It's _a_ square root of the discriminant.